# Progressive Web Apps - Navigating between multiple cached pages while offline

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, caching, progressive-web-apps

I started experimenting with progressive web apps but when it concerns offline caching, I am either misunderstanding something, or doing something wrong.

I have 2 HTML pages (`index.html` and `index2.html`) which are identical, code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test PWA</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/app_styles.css" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/icon1.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Test web app</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <a href="/index.html">Page 1</a>
        <a href="/index2.html">Page 2</a>
    </nav>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/app_scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And then below is the fetch and install event methods, as well as the cache contents, which, from my understanding, should return cached contents if there is no network, correct me if done incorrectly.

```
var CacheName = 'TestPWA_Cache';
var CacheContents = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/index2.html',
    '/assets/app_scripts.js',
    '/assets/app_styles.css',
    '/assets/icon1.png',
    '/assets/icon2.png',
    '/assets/icon3.png'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(caches.open(CacheName).then(function (cache) {
        console.log("Service worker install sucess.");
        return cache.addAll(CacheContents).then(function () {self.skipWaiting(); });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Service worker install failed! "+err);
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        if (response) return response;
        return fetch(event.request);
    }));
});
```

My issue is, when I go offline, it'll open the `index.html` page but when I try to navigate between the two pages, it gives me an error saying I'm offline, which is naturally true, but is the idea behind offline caching not supposed to cache the files in such a way that'll allow me to navigate between multiple cached pages while I'm offline?

If so, where am I going wrong?

If not, then I don't see how PWA's will replace native apps anytime soon, until they provide a method of switching between cached pages while offline.

PS. I'm experiencing this using Google Chrome on Windows and on Android.

Comment: You still have to fetch the contents of each page while you are still online;  can you show the code that actually populates your cache?

Comment: @Claies I edited to include the install event.

Comment: Look up on [service workers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers). They do awesome work for offline stuff.

Comment: @NikhilRaghavendra The javascript above, is the code of the service worker. It is the service worker doing my caching too. I'm just having an issue with how it caches.

Comment: My bad my bad... So you just need your site to be navigatable offline right? You can only open index.html and not go to index2.html, this is what you mean, am I correct?

Comment: Well yeah I can access index.html, but when navigating to index2.html, it gives me the offline error, but chrome shows the page under the cached contents so it is cached, I just can't navigate to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service worker's `fetch` event handler is triggered for navigation requests made from the clients that it controls. That's definitely one of the intended use cases for service workers.

I notice that you're not calling `self.clients.claim()` within your service worker's `activate` event. That's not a problem in and of itself, but it means that your newly installed service worker won't control the current client tab/window. It won't be until the *next* time that you visit your web app that the service worker will control the page, and start triggering the `fetch` event handler. So if you're testing offline navigations immediately after installing a fresh service worker, prior to closing and then revisiting the site, that would explain what you're seeing.

There's more information about using `self.clients.claim()` at https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/service-worker/lifecycle#clientsclaim

Comment: Implementing `clients.claim()` helped thanks. I noticed that the cache becomes available immediately so it works as I wanted it to.